# Two inputs into one

Tags: audio

The application here is a DJI (like GoPro) camera being used when motorcycle touring. We want the camera to record audio being received via a bike to bike comms system (Cardo Packtalk) as well as the rider's voice from a mic.  The total audio is transmitted to the camera via a bluetooth transmitter. The transmitter has a 3.5mm TRS female jack input.  We want to parallel the mic and audio inputs into the transmitter.  Both the mic and the audio feed from the Cardo system are on 35mm male TRS jacks.  is this possible?  We tried doing this with a 'breakout' cable but it seems the mic loaded down the Cardo audio and no sound was then audible.  I have a sense we want a 2 into 1 input where the connector 'isolates' the two input devices in some way.  Is this possible do we think?  THANKS

Answer (score 0):

#### Intro

If I understood correctly, what you want is a mixer with two inputs and one output. This is not as trivial as merging two cables together on one side. There are various ways you could do that, with varying levels of complexity too. I’ll try to provide some of the most basics and you are free to take it from there.

#### Summing with resistors

Probably the easiest (and also the “worst”) way to do it is with simple resistors. The corresponding circuit is shown below and is taken from [this](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/103436) EE SE answer where you can find more information about it.

[image: Resistor sum]

The two resistors are equal which means that the level of the two inputs will be weighted equally. Whether they end up being equal is a matter of the actual levels “reaching" the resistors.

This is not a great way to sum the signals but is an easy one and you could try it out. There is some things to take care though, based on the levels of the signals you’d like to sum. If I understood correctly, you want to sum up a microphone signal and some other incoming signal. If those two do **not** have the same level, it would be a good idea to use appropriate resistors to balance the levels. This can be a trial-and-error process, or a better solution would be to use variable resistors (potentiometers/trimmers). This way you’ll be able to even adjust the levels while the mixer is in operation. An example of that can be seen in the figure below, taken from [this](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/103437) EE SE answer.

[image: Variable resistor]

Obvisouly, the major advantage of this circuit is that it is extremely simple to make and in addition to that it is passive and does **not** require power supply. This can be a great feature for your specific application since it is not easy to integrate it to your motorcycle and going around with a pack of batteries is not always convenient.

#### A better solution (OpAmp)

A better solution would be to use an operational amplifier (OpAmp) in a summing configuration, as shown in the figure below. The figure is also taken from the the answer on EE SE with the two resistor summing circuit (replicating [link](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/103436) for convenience). I strongly suggest you have a look at this answer to get some more information.

[image: OpAmp summing circuit]

There are various components here which I am not going to discuss as this answer is not about the electronics and it already contains much of that anyway. I will only say that this is a better topology that provides better quality audio and is more robust. The downside of course is that it is an active circuit, which means that you have to provide it with power and not only that, but the quality of your power supply **does** have an effect on the resulting audio. Usually, a linear voltage regulator will be sufficient for simple applications but of course you can go fancy with switching ones, or other complex circuitry.

Similar to the “two-resistor” solution you can use variable resistors here to be able to adjust the volume.

Finally, you can find a more complete circuit schematic for this application with more components in the figure below. The second part of the circuit is an amplification stage which you may, or may not need in your application. In the simplest case you can exchange the $R13$ with a variable resistor and be able to change the overall level of your mixed signal.

#### Final remarks

Please keep in mind that I have presented two options in a kind of simplified way without going into details about the behaviour of the circuits or their implementation. Based on how much time and money (although both circuits are fairly cheap to put together) you are willing to invest you could possibly go further and add more “sophisticated features” to your circuit such as inverted polarity guards, spike protection and a whole bunch more.

I believe that giving the first circuit (two-resistors) a try is worth it since you could test it even without a circuit board, just by connecting the two signals to two resistors and their combined output to your next stage input.